# jQuery click not reacting to prevent-default-behavior

Tags: jquery

I have this site: http://www.problemio.com and if you go there and click any link that says "important" it gives you a login popup.  That popup works ok.  The problem occurs when on that dialog that pops up, you press "create_profile" link.

Instead of showing the create profile popup, it goes to the create_profile page.

Here are my click handlers:

```
$('#login').live('click' , function() 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
         // Make the existing suggestions visible
         $("#loginpopup").dialog();
         $("#createprofilepopup").dialog( 'close' );

         return false;
    }); 

    $('#signup').live('click' , function() 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#loginpopup").dialog( 'close' );
        $("#createprofilepopup").dialog( { height: 800, width: 600 } );

        return false;
    });
```

I just put the event.preventDefault(); in there but not entirely sure how it is really supposed to work.  Any advice or ideas why it isn't working as I anticipated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#login').live('click' , function() 
$('#signup').live('click' , function()
```

to:

```
$('#login').live('click' , function(event) 
$('#signup').live('click' , function(event)
```

Because you need the `event` argument, otherwise you are calling a function to an object that does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the event argument in the function signature try this.

```
$('#login').live('click' , function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
         // Make the existing suggestions visible
         $("#loginpopup").dialog();
         $("#createprofilepopup").dialog( 'close' );

         return false;
    }); 

    $('#signup').live('click' , function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#loginpopup").dialog( 'close' );
        $("#createprofilepopup").dialog( { height: 800, width: 600 } );

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the event into the click function

```
 $('#login').live('click' , function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
```